# Join tree paths for each node

Tags: javascript, node.js

This should be easy, but I am having a brain fart, I have a structure like this:

```
  interface EntitiesMap {
    name: string, 
    children: Array<EntitiesMap>,
  }
```

The tree has no cycles. So that might look like:

```
const m = {
   name: 'foo',
   children: [{
     name: 'Baz1',
     children: [ ...etc ]
     }, {
      name:'Bar',
      children:[]
   }]
}
```

For each node in the tree, I am simply looking to join the name fields.
So for example if I had this tree:

```
foo ----- Baz1 ---- Baz2 ------Baz5
 \          \           \
   Bar       \           \
              Baz3       Baz4
```

So for the foo (root) node, I would have these list of names:

```
FooBar
FooBaz1Baz2Baz5
FooBaz1Baz3
FooBaz1Baz2Baz4
```

Since we have 4 tips of the tree, then we have 4 paths for the root (foo) node.

For the `Baz1` node, we would have 3 tips:

```
Baz1Baz2Baz5
Baz1Baz2Baz4
Baz1Baz3
```

There must be a simple way of generating these strings, based off of a the EntitiesMap tree structure, but I am really struggling with it. I am looking for a good algorithm/simple that's not too clever.

Comment: I can't seem to correlate your diagram to your object structure. Are `Baz1 Baz2 Baz5` children of `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this recursively - get names for each child and concatenate "this" node's name with every result for each child:

```js
function joinNames(node) {
  if (node.children.length === 0) return [node.name];
  let names = [];
  node.children.forEach(n =>
    joinNames(n).forEach(cn =>
      names.push(node.name + cn)));
  return names;
}

const m = {
  name: 'Foo',
  children: [{
      name: 'Baz1',
      children: [{
          name: 'Baz3',
          children: []
        },
        {
          name: 'Baz2',
          children: [{
              name: 'Baz4',
              children: []
            },
            {
              name: 'Baz5',
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Bar',
      children: []
    }
  ]
};


console.log(joinNames(m));
console.log(joinNames(m.children[0])); // 'Baz1' as root
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes passing the current path as an argument to a recursive function can simplify the function and make things a little easier to understand. Here's a possible way to do that:

```js
const m = {name: 'foo',children: [{name: 'Baz1',children: [ {name: "Baz3",children: []},{name: "Baz2",children: [{name: "Baz5",children: []},{name: "Baz4",children: []}]}]}, {name:'Bar',children:[]}]}

function getPath(node, path=""){
  return (node.children.length == 0) 
    ? [path + node.name]
    : node.children.reduce((arr, child) => 
        arr.concat(...getPath(child, path + node.name)), [])
    
}
console.log(getPath(m))
```